# How do you make a bootable usb stick on OSX with a corrupted harddrive`?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, macosx

I cant access the desktop because my harddrive is corrupted. Therefore I want to make a bootable USB stick so i can transfer all of my important files to my External HD. 
Problem is that Im stuck on Step 3 ---> http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx .

Im not sure of what i should change this to:

hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso

It says convert failed - No such file or directory. Obviously the problem is that i dont know the path to the USB, maybe you know how to find out?

Please help me.
Thanks.

ps.

Ive downloaded the ubuntu desktop amd64+mac.

Answer (score 2):

Now, Mr. Nick, first of all why did you get a `.RAR` format download? Please go to http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/release to download the `amd64+mac` ISO. Then open a terminal and type

```
 hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.img ~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso
```

Then run diskutil to get the current list of devices, close it, plug in your USB, and run diskutil again. Note down the device node assigned to the USB (e.g.`/dev/disk2`).
Then unmount it: `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2`
Then enter the command:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.img of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

Then eject the USB using `diskutil eject /dev/disk2`, then remove the USB.
Finally reboot and press alt/option key to boot from USB when it is restarting.

Answer (score 0):

> Im not sure of what i should change this to:
>
> hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img
>   ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso

If the directory where the ubuntu.iso was downloaded is called Downloads.

Then you would change it as follows :

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/ubuntu.img ~/Downloads/ubuntu.iso
```