# Problem with setting up a bootable USB on corrupted OSX

Tags: installation, boot, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make a bootable usb stick on OSX with a corrupted harddrive`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182639/how-do-you-make-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-osx-with-a-corrupted-harddrive)

I cant access the desktop because my harddrive is corrupted. Therefore I want to make a bootable USB stick so i can transfer all of my important files to my External HD. Problem is that Im stuck on Step 3 ---> http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx .

Im not sure of what i should change this to:

hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso

It says convert failed - No such file or directory. Obviously the problem is that i dont know the path to the USB, maybe you know how to find out?

Please help me. Thanks.

ps.

Ive downloaded the ubuntu desktop amd64+mac.

pps.
Unetbootin is a different alternative, but i dont know if it works?